# retrofit calling id from url

Tags: android, retrofit

How I use these query in retrofit network call and display it in category wise result

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/{genre_id}/movies
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this could help:

interface class

```
public interface TheApiInterface{
     @GET("url/bits/until/{path_variable}/then/more/url")
     Call<TheThingResponse> getTheThing(@Path("path_variable") String var);
}
```

Activity or whatever:

```
public class ThePlaceYoureCallingItFrom {

    //set up the api interface and http client 
    public TheApiInterface getApi(){
        String endpoint = "https://api.root.site/api/";
        //set up retrofit object
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(endpoint)
                //add chosen converter factory for pojo serialization
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                //add the OKHTTP client
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
                //now gimme
                .build().create(TheApiInterface.class);
    }

    public void callGetTheThing(){
        //create call
        Call<TheThingResponse> call = getApi().getTheThing("somePathVar");
        //set callback
        ThingResponseCallback callback = new ThingResponseCallback(this, THING_RESPONSE_INTENT_FILTER);
        //fire
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
}
```

the callback:

```
public class ThingResponseCallback implements Callback<TheThingResponse>{
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Call<TheThingResponse> call, Response<TheThingResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: success: theResponseFieldIWant1: " + response.theResponseFieldIWant1;);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: something went wrong with the response object " +response.body());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<TheThingResponse> call, Throwable t) {
         Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: to: " + call.request().url() + " req " + call.request());
    }
}
```

the response pojo:

```
public class TheThingResponse{
    @SerializedName("theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse1")
    public String theResponseFieldIWant1;

    @SerializedName("theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse2")
    public String theResponseFieldIWant2;

    @SerializedName("theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse3")    
    public String theResponseFieldIWant3;

    @SerializedName("theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse4")    
    public String theResponseFieldIWant4;
}
```

the JSON you're receiving would look like this:

```
 {
"theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse1": "the value I wanted 1",
"theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse2": "the value I wanted 2",
"theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse3": "the value I wanted 3",
"theJsonKeyOfTheFieldReturnedInServerResponse4": "the value I wanted 4"
 }
```

but you can build more complex POJOs for more complex JSON.

I've found it useful to make my POJOs all share a Serializable parent class, to make them easy to move about in the Callback, but you could also use a ContentProvider in here quite readily and insert some rows into a DB or something like that if you want to have a more permanent storage.

But bear in mind this is all async- if you want synchronous Retrofit calls, you can use call.execute()

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean- are you asking how to call?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually I gave wrong interface class that's why it gave me error....

Comment: how do i use same thing for POST method.

Answer (score 0):

**At least in the "retrofit" library, it works like this**

```
@GET("/url/{id}")
   suspend fun getNews(
      @Path("id") searchById:String
   ):Response<News>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?